# Anexar index a los demas a archivos en la carpeta en general y dentro de archivos de subcarpetas

Tags: php, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al usar  `<? php include("index.php"); ?>` me funciona pero solo en los archivos que están en la carpeta principal, donde esta `index` y los demás archivos, pero cuando quiero enlazar el index a los archivos dentro de las carpetas, por ejemplo dentro de la carpeta ejercicios me da error y dice que el archivo no existe dentro de esa carpeta, que puedo hacer en ese caso?

Comment: Agrega tu código de los su directorios, y error que te tira

Comment: Intenta con este código `<?php include("../index.php") ?> `  Con `../` invocas al archivo que esta un directorio antes del archivo actual y así debes aplicarlo dependiendo el caso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el `index.php` está en la raís de tu proyecto, las subcarpetas debieran llamarlo como `../index.php`. Si es la subcarpeta de una carpeta, entonces sería `../../index.php` y así sucesivamente. Si el prefijo `../` en la ruta significa "subir un directorio" entonces debes aplicarlo tantas veces como niveles de profundidad de cada archivo.

```
- raíz del proyecto (require 'index.php')
  - ejemplo2 (require '../index.php')
    - ejemplos2_corregidos (require '../..index.php')
  - guia2 (require '../index.php')
```

Este método es practicable si tienes pocos directorios y pocos archivos. A medida que crece un proyecto es más sencillo tener pocos entrypoints y hacer que éstos definan una constante estableciendo la ruta fija del index para todos los otros scripts que se carguen en un request. Por ejemplo, en un archivo `_bootstrap.php` incluir:

```
<?php

  define('HOMEDIR',__DIR__);
```

Y de esa manera, en cualquier otro script que se incluya, llamarías a index.php como:

```
<?php

  require(HOMEDIR.'/index.php');
```

Para que esto funcionara, tendrías que hacer que toda visita partiera de un mismo entrypoint que a su vez la redirigiera al script que realmente buscabas mediante un parámetro. En tu caso, el mismo index.php podría ser ese entrypoint.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!! me ha servido de mucho tu ayuda!!

Answer (score -1):

un ejemplo para la carpeta "guia" seria "../guia2/index.php" y asi seria cada vez que lo quieras llamar, claro la ruta cambia dependiendo de donde lo busques